# CubeMx makefile is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, stm32

I want to program an STM32F103VCT6 microcontroller in VSCode environment. I installed the stm32-for-vscode extension. I created a project with CubeMx with Makefile toolchain setting. I can compile the code with the GNU ARM gcc compiler. The project is very simple I only configured the crystal and the serial debug.
My problem is that if I flash the code the crystal is not running, I verified with my oscilloscope. If I generate a project with CubeIde and I compile it there it works perferctly, the crystal starts. The C code is the same in the two projects.

My makefile is faulty or what?

[CubeMx project](https://github.com/bmd-studio/stm32-for-vscode/files/5233616/pedo4.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I may be late for your specific problem, but I'm going to leave an answer anyway.

I encountered the same problem, even if with a different MCU (STM32F091RC), but I was able to find a solution which may be helpful.

First, I realized that the produced binaries had different sizes.
Therefore, I analyzed the Makefile generated by CubeMX and the compilation steps performed by CubeIDE. There were some compilation flags which were different between the two, and one in particular caught my attention: the **optimization flag**.

I noticed how, in the Makefile generated by CubeMX, the flag was set to `-0g`, which according to the documentation it instructs the compiler to:

```
Optimize debugging experience.
-Og should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle,
offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good
debugging experience. It is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because
some compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0.
```

Despite the last sentence, I already had problems in the past with gcc code optimizations. Therefore, I set that flag to `-O0` and recompiled everything.
Note that I didn't need to debug anything, therefore I can't tell if using `-O0` instead of `-Og` does really affect the debug experience and at which extent.

I flashed the produced binary (with `openocd`) and everything worked correctly.

#### Note about stm32-for-vscode extension

Please notice that despite editing the Makefile correctly, this extension will generate its own Makefile, which will not take into account the change in the optimization flag we did previosuly.

Moreover, you can't just edit the Makefile generated from the extension, since it re-generates it at every run.

In order to solve this problem, I had to download the source code of the extension and recompile it by adjusting the optimization flag (also, since I had the chance I also added the `-j` option to the make command, in order to speed up the compilation).

Since this goes out of scope regarding the original question, I'm not going to dig into the details, but depending on your needs you may not need the extension at all (*e.g.* if you only need to compile, clean or flash the binary into the board).

Hope this all helps!